# Tableau: Counting values in a sub group of a column

Tags: count, tableau-desktop

I have a table that has site, staff member name, and case numbers for each staff member.  I'd like another column that shows (once) how many case numbers there are for each staff member.  Now, I have this:

| Site | StaffName | Case Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jeff | 11111 |
|  |  | 11121 |
|  |  | 13131 |
| B | Adam | 76642 |
|  |  | 30303 |
| C | Martha | 43423 |
|  |  | 12341 |
|  |  | 76546 |

I'd like to add a column that has the count per the following:

| Site | StaffName | # Cases | Case Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jeff | 3 | 11111 |
|  |  |  | 11121 |
|  |  |  | 13131 |
| B | Adam | 2 | 76642 |
|  |  |  | 30303 |
| C | Martha | 3 | 43423 |
|  |  |  | 12341 |
|  |  |  | 76546 |

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a COUNT measure on top of your "Case" field and then convert it to discrete

[image: Something like this]

Comment: That is exactly what we are trying to do.  How did you get it to scope the # of order ID's to the city?   So 1 for Aberdeen vs. all of the orders?

Comment: The counts may not look correct, but I just placed them side by side

Comment: Actually, yours do look correct.  Ours do not.  So you were able to get the count by city just by placing the calculated field between order ID and City?

Comment: Thats correct, I wish i could guide you via Zoom